# Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but identifier TUNJANGAN found

Tags: pascal, freepascal, pascalscript

```
procedure tambahData;
begin
     clrscr;
     if banyakData<Maks then
     begin
          banyakData:=banyakData+1;
          writeln('Pemasukan data ke-',banyakData);
          with Pegawai[banyakData] do
          begin
                banyakData:=banyakData+1;
          writeln('Pemasukan data ke-',banyakData);
          with Pegawai[banyakData] do
          begin
               write('NIP          : ');readln(nip);
               write('Nama         : ');readln(nama);
               write('Jabatan      : ');readln(jabatan);

               if (jabatan = 'direktur') then
                  gajiPokok := 10000000
                  tunjangan :=  0.5*gajiPokok
                  pajak := 0.10*(gajiPokok+tunjangan)
                  gajiBersih := (gajiPokok+tunjangan)-pajak
               else
                   if (jabatan = 'manajer') then
                       gajiPokok := 5000000
                       tunjangan := 0.5*gajiPokok
                       pajak := 0.10*(gajiPokok+tunjangan)
                       gajiBersih := (gajiPokok+tunjangan)-pajak
                   else
                       if (jabatan = 'staf') then
                          gajiPokok := 3000000
                          tunjangan := 0.5*gajiPokok
                          pajak := 0.10*(gajiPokok+tunjangan)
                          gajiBersih := (gajiPokok+tunjangan)-pajak
          end;
     end
     else
         writeln('Data penuh.');
     writeln('Tekan Enter Untuk Melanjutkan');  readln;
end;
```

Comment: Statements in Pascal must end with `;` but a lot of yours do not.

Comment: Although @NateEldredge is right about the problem being missing semicolons, statements in Pascal need NOT end with semicolon. However, they must be *separated* by semicolon: `begin DoThis; DoThat; DoSomething end;`

Comment: Also, the OP's code seems to lack a lot of `begin..end` blocks.

Comment: How are you learning the Pascal language? Are you working with a textbook or tutorial? You've missed some fundamentals of the language structure you need to study.